# Configure log4j log level using an external configuration file

Tags: java, configuration, log4j, configuration-files

Is it possible to configure the log4j log level using an external configuration file? Rather than have a user configure the log level in the log4j.properties file, I would like them to configure the log level using a project configuration file.

WulfgarPro

Comment: Do you plan to re-deploy your app after the log4j settings have been updated by the user? Otherwise log4j will not pick up those changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your build/make tool. For example: in Maven I do just that. In Maven there is "filtering" feature that you can enable. Maven filtering will replace ${some_property} in all your resource files with whatever the value of "some_property" is in Maven.

That is how I change my Log4J properties if I am in dev or prod mode. Other than that, I dont know if Log4J itself has such a feature.  I am sure the same is possible via Ant.

Comment: @somid3, I can extract the property with Ant .. but how do I insert it into my log4j.properties file?

Comment: I just goggled this and haven't used it [ant filtering](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/filter.html). It seems the ant notation is to surround the value with @s. Your Log4J props file would like: property_name = @some_value@ where "some_value" is defined in your build.xml

Comment: @somid3 - i'm not sure how the Filter task has anything to do with my problem. My current thought process is to remove the log4j.properties file and setup the logging level programmatically via the key-value project configuration file.

Comment: Filter is good for when you want to pass a global value to a properties file. For example your log4j.properties will have a line "log4j.rootCategory=@level@" and you can define "level" in Ant. Your project configuration will define the value for "level" and Ant will replace @level@ in your log4j.properties file -- I think that is your question, otherwise can you clarify your situation?

Comment: @somid3 - filter works. Thanks! I added something like so: `<filter token="LOG-LEVEL" value=${LOGGING}`. The LOGGING variable comes from my properties file and LOG-LEVEL is defined within log4j.properties like so: `@LOG-LEVEL@`.

Comment: awesome! now that you're doing Ant ... let me tell you about Maven! Research it, I used to use Ant, but Maven is 100% better if you need a simple build tool. It allows to you modularize and take separation of concerns to a new level. Glad filtering worked.